# ImageView is stretch when not supposed to be - Android

Tags: java, android, imageview

Column 0 is supposed to be a picture of either a red x or a green check mark.  For testing purposes, I have only put an image in for row 1.  As seen in the picture below, the red x image is long and stretched out rectangle.  I want it to be a small square image.  The image seems to be the same as displayed below even if I put the layout_width and layout_height to 50dp each, 10dp each, or as I have it below in my code.  The dimensions of the picture is 100x100 PNG picture -- if that matters.

My question is why is the image to stretched out and how would I go about making it a small square image.  Thank you in advance for your help!

Results.java

```
ImageView q1Image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.q1Image);
q1Image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
```

resultsmain.xml

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/row4"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/q1Image"
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_weight=".1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/q1Question"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:textSize="8sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/q1Answer"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:textSize="8sp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/q1Verse"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:textSize="8sp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
</TableRow>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/row4"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/q1Image"
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
       />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/q1Question"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:textSize="8sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/q1Answer"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:textSize="8sp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/q1Verse"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:textSize="8sp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
</TableRow>
```

Comment: Hey @Appu, I changed my code to what you said above.  I have edited my opening post to show the code exactly.  The result is still the same though.  If anything, the red x might be ever so slightly wider this time.  So the result is still the same.  Any other suggestions?